# CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString don't create last line

Tags: objective-c, ios

Why this code giving me only one line? but if i write @"line1\n\0", then i will have two lines! Why last '\n' don't create a new line?

```
CTFramesetterRef ctfsr = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"line1\n"]);
    CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(ctfsr, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);
    CGRect tempRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _textContentView.bounds.size.width, suggestedSize.height);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:tempRect];
    CTFrameRef ctfr = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(ctfsr, CFRangeMake(0, 0), [path CGPath], NULL);
    NSArray* lines = (__bridge NSArray*)CTFrameGetLines(ctfr);
    NSLog(@"%@", lines);
```

how to make create a new line without adding any symbol?